# How to implement a asynchronized workflow?

Tags: c#, workflow, begininvoke, asynchronous

```
        WorkflowInvoker invoker = new WorkflowInvoker(new Workflow1());

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            //invoker.InvokeAsync(myOrders);
            IAsyncResult result = invoker.BeginInvoke(myOrders,new AsyncCallback(WorkflowCompletedCallback),order);
        }
```

I use the above code to implement asynchronized workflow. I hope to run this workflow for 10 times and I have something similar with thread pool so the 10 workflow thread could run at the same time. The second doesn't need to wait for the first one finished its job. My workflow is very simple it will do some calculation and print several sentences on screen. After I run the above code, I find it seems the 10 workflows are invoked one by one not as what I hoped to run at the same time. What is the correct way to asynchronize workflow? Thank you!

Update: After some feed back from others, I also try use workflowapplication to do this asynchronizely:

```
        WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new Workflow1(), myOrders);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            wfApp.Run();
        }

        /* Read the end time. */
        DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(stopTime);
        // Duration
        TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
        Console.WriteLine("hours:" + duration.TotalHours);
        Console.WriteLine("minutes:" + duration.TotalMinutes);
        Console.WriteLine("seconds:" + duration.TotalSeconds);
        Console.WriteLine("milliseconds:" + duration.TotalMilliseconds);
```

Here is the running result:
4/8/2011 9:57:49 AM
4/8/2011 9:57:50 AM
hours:6.27777777777778E-05
minutes:0.00376666666666667
seconds:0.226
milliseconds:226
Process Order
Customer: 10 | Shipping:NextDay | Total Price:250 | Shipping Price:10
ProductID:1 | Quantity:5 | Price: 50
ProductID:2 | Quantity:10 | Price: 200

It seems it is asynchronized but only one thread is actually running my workflow (not the main application thread). But from the output I only see one thread is running my workflow. How could I let 10 threads run the workflow at the same time? Thank you!

Comment: There is no direct indication in the code provided that can explain this behavior. Do you perform some synchronization within the workflow?

Comment: no, I didn't do any synchronization in my workflow. It is very simple, just do some caculation and then print some statements.

Comment: WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new Workflow1(), myOrders);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
 wfApp.Run();
}

Comment: I change my code to above and it seems once the wfApp.Run is executed, the main thread will leave this workflow run with another thread. The main thread go to the programs following my above code. It seems wfApp.Run provide the asynchronize function. But it only execute wfApp.Run() once and remaining 9 times wfApp.Run() are not executed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're checking the `IAsyncResult` inside your loop, that will block until the async method has completed. The `IAsyncResult` is provided so that you can use an asynchronous method synchronously, which is not what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you for let me know. Then what should be the correct way to do asynchronously?

Comment: What you're doing appears to be correct, but I'm assuming you haven't included everything that happens in your actual code. Are you trying to access the value of `result` somewhere?

Comment: I want to run my workflow - the same workflow with the same parameters with ten thread running together.

Comment: And I am not trying to access the value of result.

Comment: Here is my code with workflowApplication and it's running result:

Comment: WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new Workflow1(), myOrders);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
    wfApp.Run();
   }

   /* Read the end time. */
   DateTime stopTime = DateTime.Now;
   Console.WriteLine(stopTime);
   // Duration
   TimeSpan duration = stopTime - startTime;
   Console.WriteLine("hours:" + duration.TotalHours);
   Console.WriteLine("minutes:" + duration.TotalMinutes);
   Console.WriteLine("seconds:" + duration.TotalSeconds);
   Console.WriteLine("milliseconds:" + duration.TotalMilliseconds);

Comment: 4/8/2011 9:57:49 AM
4/8/2011 9:57:50 AM
hours:6.27777777777778E-05
minutes:0.00376666666666667
seconds:0.226
milliseconds:226
Process Order
Customer: 10 | Shipping:NextDay | Total Price:250 | Shipping Price:10
ProductID:1 | Quantity:5 | Price: 50
ProductID:2 | Quantity:10 | Price: 200

Comment: so actually it is asynchronized but not run the workflow with 10 threads - it seems only one thread run one workflow

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read if you edit your question to include this code.

Answer (score 0):

Your second example is wrong since WorkflowApplication.Run is blocking.

As for your first example, see this article: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/OperationWorkflowInvoker4.aspx

especially: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/OperationWorkflowInvoker4/Operat1.jpg

It appears that WorkflowInvoker uses a dispatcher strategy which very well might be single threaded. Investigate in this or do your own thread scheduling

Comment: Thanks Polity! Do you know why this WorkflowApplication.Run is blocking? I read the example on book "Pro WF windows workflow in .net4" by bruce Bukovice. It suggests to use workflowapplication to do real asynchronization.